# Netty : Blocking call to get a connected Server Channel?

Tags: java, netty

The call on `ServerBootstrap.bind()` returns a `Channel` but this is not in a `Connected` status and thus cannot be used for writing to client.

All the examples in Netty documentation show writing to a `Channel` from its `ChannelHandler`'s events like `channelConnected` - I want to be able to get a connected Channel not in the event but as a reference outside the event , lets say some client code using my server component. One way is to manually code for waiting for `channelConnected` event and then copying the Channel reference.But this may be reinventing the wheel.

So the question is : Is there a blocking call available in Netty that returns a Connected Channel ?

edit : I am using Oio Channels , not Nio.

Comment: Why? You can't get a channel to a client till he connects, and that comes to you as a connect event. Why do you think you need another mechanism? and why a blocking mechanism? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I know I cannot get a connected channel until the client connects .. thats exactly why I mention blocking .. lets say there is an external interface that wants a connected channel ( for writing something ) . the server has to wait ( block) until client connects and return this connected channel.. which part does not make sense ?

Comment: None of it makes sense. If it's a client connection, you can't force it to happen, you have to process the inbound connection event as it arrives. Are you possibly talking about an *outbound* connection? To another *server?*

Comment: Its not outbound. The server indeed is listening for clients to connect, and they will eventually connect , which is when the event will get fired , and connection will be established. But the server has also to serve another external interface that is interested in writing to clients ( thru the server ) and which has its own timing for requesting a channel .. now when this external interface calls the server for a connected channel , the server has to block this call until a client establishes a connection .. does that help a bit ?

Comment: I have thought of a synch thread and a blocking queue approach. If Netty has anything like what a java.net.ServerSocket has ( a blocking call that returns a Channel that is ready to be used for writing ) then I can use that API as well. - thats why my question ..too bad to know there no such API..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a blocking call, but I think you maligned the event based approach too quickly. This is a contrived example, just to make sure I understand what you're trying to do:

1. Netty Server starts
2. A *DataPusher* service starts.
3. When a client connects, the DataPusher grabs a reference to the client channel and writes some data to it.
4. The client receives the pushed data shortly after connecting.

More or less correct ?

To do this, your DataPusher (or better yet, one of its minions) can be registered as a ChannelHandler in the server pipeline you create. Make it extend [org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelHandler.html). The handler might look like this:

```
DataPusher dataPusher = getMyDataPusherReference();

public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
   dataPusher.doYourThing(e.getChannel());  // do something in another thread....
}
```

If you are determined to make it a blocking call from the DataPusher's perspective, just have it wait on a latch and have the minion drop the latch.

Not sure if that's what your'e looking for.....

Comment: You figured out my use case more or less correct. Now the solution you mention , the issue with that is : the DataPusher is not as simple as it sounds. it has a set of connected activities to do and all this means it is best to hand it a channel to write rather than trying to squeeze its nature into a ChannelHandler mould.

Comment: Right. The handler can be simply "DataPusher" aware, so it knows both when a new connection is made and how to pass the channel to the DataPusher. You could also register all connected channels in a ChannelGroup and then the DataPusher simply needs a reference to the ChannelGroup and a "lightweight nudge" when a new channel is added to it. Or.... override ChannelGroup and add in your own event handling.

Answer (score 1):

After all the exchanges above, I still don't see that any of this is necessary.

Surely all you have to do is just accept the connection from the external service; don't register it for any events; then, when the other client connects, register for I/O events on both channels.

The external service doesn't know or care whether you are blocked in a thread waiting for another connection, or just not responding for some other reason.

If he's writing to you, his writes will succeed anyway, up to the size of your socket receive buffer, whether you are blocking or not, as long as you aren't actually reading from him. When that buffer fills up, he will block until you read some of it.

If he is reading from you, he will block until you send something, and again what you are doing in the meantime is invisible to him.

So I think you just need to simplify your thinking, and align it more with the wonderful world of non-blocking I/O.